# Need help in xamarin form Design

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am making an app using Portable xamarin form (cross platform) having android and IOS project.

I am having designing issue.

Below is my code.

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" >

    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="20,30,20,0">
      <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="#6E335E" Padding="10,0,10,0" >
        <Label Text="{ Binding CompanyName }" FontSize="18"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" ></Label>

      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="130"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20,0,20,0">
      <Image  Source="{ Binding LogoPath }" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>

    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0,10,30" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
      <Image  Source="image_bottom.png" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
    </StackLayout>

  </Grid>
```

Below is the image Which describe how i want design

[image]

Please help me in designing issue.

Thanks in anvance

Comment: I see couple of difference, rounded corner, there is whitespace in the second picture. Could you point the features that you're trying to implement?

Comment: I want to remove space between Mexican image and purple Bar

Comment: Can you clarify what the name of the element in the code that's mispositioned? Is it image_bottom.png? Is it the element you're setting with {Binding LogoPath}?

Comment: image_bottom.png is image in purple color and {binding logoPath} is a Image above purple color bar (image_bottom.png)

Comment: @KirtiZare Try to set padding for StackLayout with LogoPath  image

Answer (score 0):

Your stacklayout has a height of 130 so the row definition is only expanding to that point. You should set the definition to *, and the grid vertical options to fillandexpand so it will fillout the remainder of space.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions >
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```